# Posting video to facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have succesfully posted video by below code

```
        File file1  = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "a.3gp");
            request = Request.newUploadVideoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), file1, new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    //appLink=null;
                    if (response.getError() == null) {
                        Logs.e(DEBUG_FACEBOOK_PUBLISH, "publish success");
                        if (uploadListener != null) {
                            uploadListener.onSuccess(null);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Logs.e(DEBUG_FACEBOOK_PUBLISH, "publish error: "
                                + response.getError().getErrorMessage());
                        Logs.e(DEBUG_FACEBOOK_PUBLISH, "publish error: "
                                + response.getError().toString());
                        if (uploadListener != null) {
                            uploadListener
                            .onError("Facebook can't publish your content");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
request.executeAsync();
```

> in this scenario first i have to download the video from url and save
>   it on the sd card after that i can upload video usig
>   **newUploadVideoRequest** method but  in ios they just passing the url and call the **requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"** method. So
>   how can  we do that in android so i don't have to download the video
>   and then post it instead of that i can directly post that video using that
>   url.

I have seen this url
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video

Comment: Are you using facebook sdk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Facebook sdk 3.14 and the code below is working just fine

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("name", give a title);
postParams.putString("type", "link"); 
postParams.putString("link", enclosing url you want to share);    
Request request = new Request(session,"me/feed" , postParams,
            HttpMethod.POST, callback);
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

and this will be the callback

```
Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
      FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
      if(error!=null){
       something went wrong
     }else{
       successfully posted
      }
    }

};
```

Try this and give a feedback.

Comment: request.executeAsync() or task.execute(); ?

Comment: hi this will post a link of video  but i want to share video directly that i can watch  on facebook .

Comment: @Raj task.execute() itself why ?

Comment: video posted sucessfully but it is posting a link of that video when i click on that link it will navigate me to that app and and from  that i can watch video this is ok , but i want to share video in a way that i can directly watch it on facebook in ios they can do that by giving just a url in some graph api method

Comment: Why you need that.?You can watch the videos on Facebook itself..Are sharing playable url instead of enclosing url ?.Ok then I guess it depends on the links you share in my case I am sharing youTube video urls.

Comment: yes it is playable url and when they in ios they they can post that url and can directly watch it on facebook but same thing does't work in android

Comment: Ok understood can you just hard code a url like this one "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9CKG9WBq2s"  and see whether this matches your requirement. ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84045/discussion-between-raj-and-sunil-sunny).